# Firing code on load of page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I have this code tied to a button that when clicked, executes code to hide a table row:

```
<script>
       $(function hideinstr() {
           $('tr.parent td').on("click", "input.instr", function () {
             var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
             $('tr.child-' + idOfParent).toggle('slow');
           });
       });
</script>
```

I would like this code to execute by default when the page loads, and let the user click the button if the want to reveal the table row.  How can I do this when the 'click' is built right into this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution never executes the function `hideinstr()`. Also, consider using [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) if your code is executed in the `<head>`. Add extra parentheses to execute the function, or remove the surrounding function (function hideinstr).

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function hideinstr() {
       $('tr.parent td').on("click", "input.instr", function () {
         var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
         $('tr.child-' + idOfParent).toggle('slow');
       });
   }());
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(
       $('tr.parent td').on("click", "input.instr", function () {
         var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
         $('tr.child-' + idOfParent).toggle('slow');
       });
   );
</script>
```

And to execute the event script directly, use `$('tr.parent td').click();`.

Comment: How will that make it fire on page load?

Comment: The function is executed on the "click" built in.  When the button is clicked, the function works.  See http://www.faithripple.com/index.htm.

Comment: It was not clear in your original question what you wanted. To execute the hide instructions section immediately, use `$('tr.parent td').click();`. However, what you should really do is change the style of `$('tr.parent td').css('display','none');` or change style directly on the element.

Comment: In my original question, following the example I said, "I would like this code to execute by default when the page loads, and let the user click the button if they want to reveal the table row. How can I do this when the 'click' is built right into this code?"

Comment: Your original question did not specify the initial state of the html. For all I know, the div could have been hidden to start, and you were having trouble getting the onclick function to fire.